# Rails validates_format_of with Regex fails in case of new line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, validation, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to validate a alphanumeric input which allow whitespaces and new lines

```
 validates_format_of :field, with: /^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/, multiline: true, allow_blank: true
```

in my form I enter this input:

[image: input]

And its accepted and pass the validation

The desired behavior is to only accept alphanumeric text (allow blank) and accept spaces/new-lines anywhere in the text. So only reject input if contain any alphanumeric char

Comment: Use `/\A[a-zA-Z0-9\n ]*\z/` or `/\A[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*(?:\R[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)*\z/`

Comment: Thanks but this reject multi line input

Comment: Which one? Have you tried the second regex?

Comment: the first, the second one is perfect and does the required. thanks very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
/\A[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*(?:\R[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)*\z/
```

See the [**Rubular**](http://rubular.com/r/qSybEdtJkT) demo.

**Details**

- `\A` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*` - 0 or more letters, digits or spaces
- `(?:\R[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)*` - 0 or more repetitions of

  - `\R` - line break
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*` - 0 or more letters, digits or spaces
- `\z` - end of string.

Comment: using  `validates_format_of :policy, with: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9\u0621-\u064A ]*(?:\R[a-zA-Z0-9\u0621-\u064A ]*)*\z/, multiline: true, allow_blank: true`      doesn't accept arabic chars even though in rails console it matches correclty. do you have an idea if rails form encode the arabic string in a different code?

Comment: @SelimAlawwa You may allow any letters if you use `\p{L}`: `/\A[\p{L}0-9 ]*(?:\R[\p{L}0-9 ]*)*\z/`. To also allow diacriics, use `/\A[\p{L}\p{M}0-9 ]*(?:\R[\p{L}\p{M}0-9 ]*)*\z/`. Also, you may remove `multiline: true`.

Answer (score 0):

I added some whitelist comma and full stop.

```
format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9 ,.;'"+-?!%$]*(?:\R[a-zA-Z0-9 ,.;'"+-?!%$]*)*\z/}
```